# laravel 4 where to store select field values? database or array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table e.g.

```
- id (PK)
- name
- manufacturer_id
- material_id
- strength_id
```

And now my question is, where I should store the id -> values?
Should I create a new table for each foregin key? E.g. manufacturers, materials, strengths?
Or should I save them into an array and access them with a helper or save it in a parent Model?

Which is the better method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is create a new table and a corresponding model for each entity. With Laravel (and Eloquent) you can easily add relations within the models.

See the following docs for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The better method is to create separate tables for each item.  This gives you the ability to join using your database.  If you want to avoid joins you still have the option of pulling the data from each table and putting them into arrays, then looking up by key.